Is "Contributor" a safe custom type name?
I am developing a site that contains essays and events. I want to create a custom post type to give each essay author and event speaker their own entry.
I know that "author" is a reserved term (as listed in https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) and it cannot be used as a CPT name.
Is it safe to use "contributor" as CPT name instead?

Yes, it is safe to use "contributor" as a custom post type (CPT) name since it's not a reserved term in WordPress.

Thank you @GyanendraGiri

I'd still recommend to prefix the technical $post_type name with a namespace specific to your plugin/site. You can then still label it any way you want.

@kraftner yes, I had the same idea:
register_post_type( 'PC_contributor', $args );

sorry, my bad: capital letters are NOT allowed in post type names. It should be
register_post_type( 'pc_contributor', $args );

@kraftner's comment here is sooooo important and I really wish more developers would apply this logic.  I inherit a ton of sites that use really generic names for things and then clients install plugins that use generic names and it's gets messy, fast.
